# Merging a branch that is ahead and behind master

Tags: github, merge, branch

This should be a really easy question to answer, but I don't trust myself when it comes to github buttons.  Not used to not using git commands.  Anyway.  I have a pull request that is both behind and ahead of master.  It states there is no conflict.  There is this tempting little button that says "merge pull request."  So, will this merge button resolve both ahead and behind states and keep master happy?  Or do I need to pull master into the branch first and then commit?